# how to combine two expressions in one driver

Tags: drivers

im trying to create random flickering material, but i need it to flicker not in every frame. To make it flicker randomly i added driver expression to 4d noise texture in W: "frame/1", so when animation plays texture flickers in every frame differently. But i want it to flicker every 3 frames like this: 000111000111000111 and so on. To do this i have to add driver expression to the same 4d noise texture in W "frame % 6 > 2" then it flickers for 3 frames, but always in the same way! Can you image? How can i combine this two expressions, so it flicker for 3 frames AND stay random?

to be more precise im trying to create shader similar to one from this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SLVihigKl_o but around 45 second mark i need to add there another expression, so the shader wont flicker like 0123456789, but 000111222333444... nahimsayin

Comment: Have you tried to multiply the expressions? *(frame%6>2)* * *(frame/1)* because 0 * x = 0 and 1 * x = x. Alternatively, use the Python expression *(frame/1) if (frame%6>2) else 0*